# c# static list of delegates to get/set same property on list of instances

Tags: c#, list, get, set, static-methods

I am creating runtime types of the same base class, each having common properties (from the base class) plus fields custom to the runtime type that are defined in a definition class which is retrieved from a database. Ideally, I would like to create two static dictionaries `Getters` and `Setters` each having the property name (for the common properties) or definition name (for the custom fields) as key and a delegate to the get or set method. I am using compiled expressions for the properties, which are called at runtime, and it seems to work. But I am struggling to find a way to add the custom fields to this dictionary.

The reason to do so, is my domain logic does not care if a field happens to be standard (a property of the class) or custom (a field in a list) it treats them identical. And each installation will have unique custom types, each with an undetermined (at compile time) number and type of fields.

Is it possible to statically compile delegates to the individual list item property at runtime, in order to invoke it fast for many instances (without reflecting each instance). I have dozens of base classes, each will have a number of different runtime types, each of which may have 100's to 100's of millions of instances, so both flexibility and performance are essential.

Boiled down to the essence, this is what the code looks like:

```
public class CustomField
{
   public FieldDefinition Definition { get; set; } 
   // Value is the property that needs to be called from delegate
   public int Value { get; set; } // int as example, could be any value type
}

public class BaseClass
{
   public EntityDefinition Definition { get; set; } 
   public int StandardField1 { get; set; } // int as example, could be any value type
   public int StandardField2 { get; set; } // int as example, could be any value type
   // more properties for standard fields...

   public List<CustomField> CustomFields { get; set; } 

   // need to add get/set of Value property of each instance of CustomFields to these
   // key is the name of the property or field (same as its definition), value is the delegate
   private static Dictionary<string, Func<object, object>> Getters; 
   private static Dictionary<string, Action<object, object>> Setters;
}

public class EntityDefinition
{
   public string Name { get; set; } // name of the custom type of object
   public List<FieldDefinition> CustomFields { get; set; } // this maps 1-to-1 to CustomFields instance of BaseClass runtime types.
}

public class FieldDefinition
{
   public string Name { get; set; } // name of the field, used as key in Getters/Setters
   // other properties
}
```

In the above if the base class has 12 properties and 20 custom fields I would expect `Getters` and `Setters` to each have 32 items. How to add the 20 custom fields are in question here.

Comment: You could emit them your self, or use expressions which can in turn be cached, and will be lot fast then reflection

Comment: @00110001, yes I use expressions for performance. The problem is that the expression is identical for each item in the list since they all point at the same property in the same class. And to distinguish between instances is only possible at run time.